# Being told to DIE with Python Requests (ically.net reading emails)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

So I am trying to scrape my current email, which can be accessed via (https://ically.net/mail.php), while trying to scrape this site,

```
headers = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"}
email = "icall3.amfoamfom@mf.net" #just some random email
def readEmail(email):
    s = requests.Session()
    logger.info(f"Using: {email}")
    encodedBytes = base64.b64encode((str(email)).encode("utf-8"))
    base = str(encodedBytes, "utf-8")
    url = f"https://ically.net/#/{base}"

    resp = s.get("https://ically.net/user.php",data={"user":email},headers=headers)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    resp = s.get("https://ically.net/mail.php?unseen=1",data={"unseen":1},headers=headers)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    resp = s.get("https://ically.net/mail.php")
    resp.raise_for_status()
    print(resp.text)
```

I end up keeping the same cookies and since I am not changing my email address it should show me my latest email,  however when I make this request my output is **DIE**. Which feels a bit harsh. Regardless I wanted to ask for help with scraping/seeing if I can improve what I am attempting to do. (I would prefer to continue to use the requests library and not use bs4 for what I am doing).

Response Headers:

```
"{'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Sun, 15 Mar 2020 04:44:32 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '23', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/7.0.33, PleskLin', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Set-Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=f5m6q05nutvkoon1rn432l8ke1; path=/', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
[Finished in 2.4s]"
```

Comment: Let me rephrase: Don't add data to the comment section!

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

The URL is just an empty page, nothing's wrong with your code.

Have you tried doing https://ically.net/#/mail.php instead of https://ically.net/mail.php ?

Comment: Yes I have, feel free to load /#/mail.php, it does something super strange where it "loads" the site but it doesnt have any content, ive tried having a wait timer however that still doesn't work. ically.net/mail.php actually has content if youve got a registered email and shows the most recent emails also.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code isn't designating any email address to view, so a harsh response is warranted.

If you go to ically.net, open up your browser's network inspector and type in an email address, you can see that there's a GET request to e.g. `https://ically.net/user.php?user=something%40iron.ically.net`, followed by the `https://ically.net/mail.php?unseen=1` request.

If you make these two requests in the same `requests` Session (to keep track of cookies), things will probably be different...

```
import requests
sess = requests.Session()
# if you like, enable this...
# sess.headers["user-agent"] = "something/something"
resp = sess.get("https://ically.net/user.php", params={"user": "something@iron.ically.net"})
resp.raise_for_status()
resp = sess.get("https://ically.net/mail.php")
resp.raise_for_status()
print(resp.text)
```

Comment: A: Thank you for the comment about session storing cookies, I didn't know that it stored cookies.
B: So I played around with this some more, you are right the get request I had completely forgot to account for, however I am still unable to read the latest mail message. Also i assume you meant mail.php since there isnt an email.php.

Comment: I really appreciate your response :) still trying to figure out how to read the messages, I can get a response however my response is just empty, which makes me wonder if I am reading the wrong thing. However its better then getting the response of DIE. I added a 30 second response to see if it was just a timer thing however it seems to still not being reading it.